# How to unmarshall a list of case class in Spray

Tags: xml, scala, spray, spray-client

First time Spray user failing to find any proper examples on this anywhere. I'm looking to unmarshall the XML API response that contains a `List[Person]`.

Say `case class Person(name: String, age: Int)`. The unmarshaller should produce the appropriate `List[Person]`.

Spray has a default `NodeSeqUnmarshaller` but I can't figure out how to chain things properly, would be grateful for any pointers.

Comment: Have you defined a JsonFormat for your case class, as defined here: https://github.com/spray/spray-json#providing-jsonformats-for-case-classes ?

Comment: @lpiepiora Not sure what that has to do with XML unmarshalling.

Comment: ah, sorry my bad for whatever reason I thought you're talking about JSON, forget about it

Comment: @flavian, Is Daryl's answer correct?  Did you forget to accept it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to solve this problem in my application. Here is some code based on your example case class that you might find to be helpful.

My approach uses `Unmarshaller.delegate` as discussed [here](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-httpx/unmarshalling/#deriving-unmarshallers).

```
import scala.xml.Node
import scala.xml.NodeSeq
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling._
import spray.httpx.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller._

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)

object Person {
  def fromXml(node: Node): Person = {
    // add code here to instantiate a Person from a Node
  }
}

case class PersonSeq(persons: Seq[Person])

object PersonSeq {
  implicit val PersonSeqUnmarshaller: Unmarshaller[PersonSeq] = Unmarshaller.delegate[NodeSeq, PersonSeq](MediaTypes.`text/xml`, MediaTypes.`application/xml`) {
    // Obviously, you'll need to change this function, but it should
    // give you an idea of how to proceed.
    nodeSeq =>
      val persons: NodeSeq = nodeSeq \ "PersonList" \ "Person"
      PersonSeq(persons.map(node => Person.fromXml(node))
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, found the delegate method in the mean time.

Comment: @flavian - Please "accept" my answer, if you agree that it's the way to solve the problem. Thanks.